# How fix error Xcode. Lexical preprocessor issue Cordova/CDVJpegHeaderWriter.h' file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I moved the project to another mac to get this error ((read a lot of answers to these questions but I did not help ((please help

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure the `Framework` and all it's `headers` are `imported` into your project properly.

Also in your `Build Settings` set `YES` to `Always search user paths`, and make sure your User header paths are pointing to the Framework.

`Clean` the project once.

Comment: How does one "make sure the Framework and all its headers are imported into your project properly"? A link would be helpful.