# xcode saying cannot find ZBarSDK.h, however it is in my project

Tags: ios, xcode, build, zbar

The build error I am getting is the following:

> Lexical or preprocessor issue 'ZBarSDK.h' file not found

I see it under my project, what do I need to do to get the build to find it?

I've tried dragging it into my main project folder.

Comment: Have you check that all the file are imported in your project?

Comment: Please check below answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25903432/how-fix-error-xcode-lexical-preprocessor-issue-cordova-cdvjpegheaderwriter-h-f

Comment: Make sure you give path in target->build setting-> framework search path.

Comment: i have 'always search user paths' set to yes =\

Answer (score 5, accepted):

forgot ZBarSDk this already included in AVFoundation frame work 
use this

try this on ios 7 and newer

to Capture QR code:

```
- (IBAction)Capture:(id)sender {

  isFirst=true;
 _session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    _device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    NSError *error = nil;

    _input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:_device error:&error];
    if (_input) {
        [_session addInput:_input];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }

    _output = [[AVCaptureMetadataOutput alloc] init];
    [_output setMetadataObjectsDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    [_session addOutput:_output];

    _output.metadataObjectTypes = [_output availableMetadataObjectTypes];

    _prevLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:_session];
    _prevLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
    _prevLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:_prevLayer];

    [_session startRunning];
}
```

To read use its delegate methode:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputMetadataObjects:(NSArray *)metadataObjects fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
    CGRect highlightViewRect = CGRectZero;
    AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *barCodeObject;
    NSString *detectionString = nil;
    NSArray *barCodeTypes = @[AVMetadataObjectTypeUPCECode, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Mod43Code,
            AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN8Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode93Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode128Code,
            AVMetadataObjectTypePDF417Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode, AVMetadataObjectTypeAztecCode];

    for (AVMetadataObject *metadata in metadataObjects) {
        for (NSString *type in barCodeTypes) {
            if ([metadata.type isEqualToString:type])
            {
                barCodeObject = (AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *)[_prevLayer transformedMetadataObjectForMetadataObject:(AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *)metadata];
                highlightViewRect = barCodeObject.bounds;
                detectionString = [(AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *)metadata stringValue];
                break;
            }
        }

        if (detectionString != nil)
        {
            if (isFirst) {
            isFirst=false;
            _label.text = detectionString;
            break;
           }
        }
        else
            _label.text = @"(none)";
    }

    _highlightView.frame = highlightViewRect;
}
```